# Convert Object Text To Time

Tags: python, pandas

I have two columns `First` and `Last`(both dtypes are object) that I would like to turn them into time variables, lets call it `First_time`, `Last_time`.

```
Current Dataframe

ID  First   Last
1    7:30a      4p
2    10a       6p
3    7p      3:30a

Desired Dataframe

ID  First   Last
1    07:30    16:00
2    10:00    18:00
3    19:00    03:30
```

I found a useful site here https://www.journaldev.com/23365/python-string-to-datetime-strptime and have tried to apply the following code `DF['hour'] = pd.to_datetime(DF['Last'], format='%H').dt.hour`

However, I get the following error and I can tell it has something to do with the text next to the number. It's a long error so I will just post the lines in red:

```
TypeError: Unrecognized value type: <class 'str'>
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
ValueError: unconverted data remains: p
```

Answer (score 3):

Re-read that link you posted.  The table clearly delineates the accepted formats.  `4p` is not in any of these formats.  However, `4pm` *is* in one of those, the %p specification.  Start with

```
DF['hour'] = pd.to_datetime(DF['Last']+['m'], format='%H%p').dt.hour
```

and work from there.

Comment: nice one `pd.to_datetime(df['First'] + ['m'],format='%H%p').dt.time` works for me , unsure why I have to enclose the `m` in a list, I get a numpy is nat ufunc error otherwise.

Comment: My mistake as well -- you have to add it as a list element, because that's consistent with the types supported for vectorized operations.  I've updated my answer to match.

Comment: I come up with the same `pd.to_datetime(df['start'].add('m'), format='%I%p').dt.hour`

Comment: Ah my mistake here - I forgot to mention that some of the Last times are displayed with the minutes 4:30 therefore I'm getting an error: ValueError: time data '4:30pm' does not match format '%H%p' (match). Also since there are also AM times, how would I add incorporate '%H%a?'

Comment: All of this is included in the documentation you referenced in your question.  Where are you stuck with that?

Comment: I removed the :30 from that times which have it; however, when running this code, It returns, for example, for 7a = 7.0 and 4p = 4.0. I need the times to appear in as a 24 hour clock so I add them back to a date (e.g. for 4p I would like 16:00:00).